# Magento PDF Invoice - order of the totals

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I have configured the `Magento PDF invoices`, and I have problems with the totals section on the bottom of the PDF document.

Its displayed like: 
 1. Subtotal
 2. Shipping tax
 3. Product Tax
 4. Tax total
 5. Shipping cost 
 6. Grand total

Is there a way to display shipping cost right below the Subtotal.. ?

Is there a way in general to influence `Magento PDF invoices` through `.xml layout files / phtml files`?

I know about `abstract` and `invoice.php` but it seems that it is not possible to solve this problem there..

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 3):

The sorting of these fields are handled by the `sort_order` attribute of each totals list item.

The `sort_order` values are stored in:

> app/code/core/Mage/Sales/etc/config.xml

For all rows except the Tax row witch is stored in

> app/code/core/age/Tax/etc/config.xml

If you copy these files to `app/code/local/` and alter these values you can manipulate the order to your needs.

Comment: This is working for everything except "Shipping" which isn't defined here. A different approach that will take care of all totals, is adding something like

    `$totals['subtotal']['sort_order']=100;`
    `$totals['discount']['sort_order']=200;`
    `$totals['shipping']['sort_order']=300;`
    `$totals['tax']['sort_order']=500;`
    `$totals['grand_total']['sort_order']=700;`

after

    `$totals = Mage::getConfig()->getNode('global/pdf/totals')->asArray();`

in

`app\code\local\Mage\Sales\Model\Order\Pdf\Abstract.php`

Answer (score 2):

You can find in Admin Panel in "Configuration->Sales->Checkout Total Sort Order" a simple way to configure the order of totals in your invoices.

Answer (score 0):

TO change in PDF you have to change in

app/code/core/Mage/Sales/etc/pdf.xml

```
 <total name="subtotal">
        <title translate="true">Subtotal</title>
        <source_field>subtotal</source_field>
        <font_size>7</font_size>
        <display_zero>true</display_zero>
        <sort_order>200</sort_order>
    </total>
```

and **sort orders** mentioned here.

extend file from /var/www/html/vendor/magento/module-sales/etc/pdf.xml